# Web scraping to get prices of used vehicles from olx

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to python. I recently learned python and as my first project, I decided to create a web scraper for OLX which would give me the various ads of SUV's with their prices and links since we are planning to buy a vehicle so I thought that not only would it be a good project but I will also be using it in real-time.
The link to the website is - https://www.olx.in/pune_g4059014/cars_c84
I want it to send me the name, price, and link of the ad relevant to my search.

The name and price are in the span class but since I have no knowledge of CSS I don't understand what it means and how to extract the data in it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bduuK.png)

Mercedes-Benz C-Class 250 Avantgarde, 2018, Diesel
This is how the name is stored.

₹ 33,50,000
This is how the price is stored.

Kindly help me out!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a scraping framework or a html parser, you can do some very basic scraping using regular expressions with [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

As you've noticed, all if the information is stored within `<span>` tags. Additionally each of those tags has a `data-aut-id="something"` where something is the information within the tags. So you can build a regular expression (regex) for each of the information you care about.

`re.findall` will find all occurrences of the tag and extract what's in it (using a capturing group) to a list. You can then zip all these lists together.

To find get the ad link, you will have to pull it out of the `href` param in the `<a>` tags. Conveniently, all the cars are in list item `<li>` with `data-aut-id="itemBox"` so the regex can just look for the first `href` after that.

```
import requests
import re

url_base = "https://www.olx.in"
url = url_base + "/pune_g4059014/cars_c84"

info_labels = ("itemPrice", "itemTitle", "itemDetails", "item-location")
info_pattern = r'(?s)<span.*?data-aut-id="{}".*?>(.*?)</span>'
link_pattern = r'(?s)<li.*?data-aut-id="itemBox".*?href="([^"]+?)"'

response = requests.get(url)
cars = list(zip(
    *(re.findall(pattern.format(label), response.text) for label in info_labels),
    (url_base + path for path in re.findall(link_pattern, response.text))
))

cars[:3]
[('₹ 38,50,000',
  'Audi A6 2.0 TDI Premium Plus, 2018, Diesel',
  '2018 - 10,500 km',
  'Shivaji Nagar, Pune',
  'https://www.olx.in/item/audi-a6-20-tdi-premium-plus-2018-diesel-iid-1559999282'),
 ('₹ 19,00,000',
  'Ford Endeavour 2017 Diesel Well Maintained',
  '2017 - 60,000 km',
  'Lumbini nagar, Pune',
  'https://www.olx.in/item/ford-endeavour-2017-diesel-well-maintained-iid-1570685051'),
 ('₹ 33,50,000',
  'Mercedes-Benz C-Class 250 Avantgarde, 2018, Diesel',
  '2018 - 20,000 km',
  'Shivaji Nagar, Pune',
  'https://www.olx.in/item/mercedes-benz-c-class-250-avantgarde-2018-diesel-iid-1554189590')]
```

You can then use the csv library to output it!

Comment: If i want it to find the information having certain words, how can i do that? I want it to give me only the SUV ads so i want the ads to contain words like say XUV or Scorpio or Fortuner(names of the vehicles) how can i do that

Comment: and this code doesnt give me the link to the advertisement.

Comment: @Phoenix - Updated to add the links. You can to your own filtering for SUVs however you'd like, e.g. `cars = list(filter(lambda car: any(keyword in car[1] for keyword in ("SUV", "Scorpio", "Fortuner")), cars))`, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Phoenix, Happy to have helped. If I have answered your question sufficiently, please mark it as such :)